# I'm trying to create checkboxes off of an array and have the boxes change daily

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new here and if I make any mistakes I apologize. Currently I'm having a problem with my JS, the code runs correctly as a list but when I swap out the `<ul>` and the `<li>` tags to make it into an input and checkboxes, the input field is displayed but there isn't any checkboxes and the list disappears. My next step is to make the list change daily, based on the array but I can't even get the checkboxes to load first.

```js
const dailyTasks = [
  set0 = ['Take the trash out', 'Check dishwasher', 'Let Daki out', 'Check indeed', 'Check email'],
  set1 = ['Check for milk', 'Check for coffee creamer'],
  set2 = ['Make tea', 'Go to bed early'],
  set3 = ['Apply for software jobs'],
  set4 = ['Check schedule at work', 'Check bank account', 'Pay bills'],
  set5 = ['Go to Chiropractor', 'Guild WvW night'],
  set6 = ['Work on coding projects, like this one', 'Do things with NODE'],
  set7 = ['Laundry', 'Movie night', 'Continue coding projects']
]

function makeDailyList(array) {
  let list = document.createElement('ul');
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
    list.appendChild(item);
  }
  return list;

}
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(makeDailyList(dailyTasks[0]));
makeDailyList(dailyTasks.set0);

/*
makeDailyList(dailyTasks.set1);
makeDailyList(dailyTasks.set3);
makeDailyList(dailyTasks.set4);
makeDailyList(dailyTasks.set5);
makeDailyList(dailyTasks.set6);
makeDailyList(dailyTasks.set7);
*/
```

Comment: what is an Item?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit the question (the snippet specifically) to add whatever element that has the `id` of "list". And fix the error for `item is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

The input array was syntactically wrong. If it's an array of arrays (aka 2D array), then the keys `set1,...setN` doesn't exist. Arrays do not have keys that are strings like `"set1"` -- arrays have real numbers for keys which are called indexes, starting at 0. Moreover if that array of arrays was an array of objects then those keys would be valid **if** they had colons`:` instead of `=`.

```
let wrong = [invalid = ['not', 'right'],...]
let correct = [['this', 'is', 'correct'],...]
```

In the function `makeDailyList(array)`, none of the `<li>` were ever created and the `<ul>` was never appended to the DOM. Also, when rereferring to one of the sub-arrays of `dailyTasks` use the index bracket notation:

```
// Get the 4th sub-array 

let fourth = dailyTasks[3]

// Remember, arrays start at 0 index
// So the fourth sub-array at index 3 is: ['Apply for software jobs']
```

```js
const dailyTasks = [
  ['Take the trash out', 'Check dishwasher', 'Let Daki out', 'Check indeed', 'Check email'],
  ['Check for milk', 'Check for coffee creamer'],
  ['Make tea', 'Go to bed early'],
  ['Apply for software jobs'],
  ['Check schedule at work', 'Check bank account', 'Pay bills'],
  ['Go to Chiropractor', 'Guild WvW night'],
  ['Work on coding projects, like this one', 'Do things with NODE'],
  ['Laundry', 'Movie night', 'Continue coding projects']
]

function makeDailyList(array) {
  let list = document.createElement('ul');
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    let chx = document.createElement('input');
    chx.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    item.append(chx);
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
    list.appendChild(item);
    /* comment out the next line if you want the list to be elsewhere */
    document.body.append(list);
  } /* uncomment the next line if you want to add theb list somewhere else. */
  // return list;
}
/* Comment this line if you want to add the list elsewhere */
makeDailyList(dailyTasks[4]);

/* Uncomment the next lines if you want the list added elsewhere */
// const list = makeDailyList(dailyTasks[4]);
// document.querySelector('fieldset').append(list);
```

```html
<fieldset></fieldset>
```

BTW, in the question you mentioned that you got it working except for checkboxes:

1. As the OP code is now, I find it hard to believe that anything actually worked at all.
2. There's no evidence of any attempt at creating, modifying, or adding any `<input>` at all. Please add that part of the code as well since I have no idea where you want checkboxes. I probably assume that the checkboxes should be added to each `<li>`. I also expect text and maybe some additional elements that are probably not needed.

Comment: Yesterday it was displaying the list in set0 when I would go into a live view, but I ripped it apart and put it back together so many times, I might not have the correct iteration and I didn't back anything up(lesson learned).

There is no evidence because I was trying to take the UL and LI inputs, and switch the ``document.createElement('ul');`` to ``document.createElement('input');`` and it was giving me a blank box, so I asked in discord and was told to put a ``input.type = "checkbox";`` under the  ``document.createElement('input');`` but it didnt seem to do anything.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to turn the ``<li>`` into check boxes. I'm trying to find the iteration of the code that did run now, but I didn't back it up.

Comment: OK, well turning rendered HTML into some other HTML would be an anti-pattern. It would be semantically and logically a better choice to create an `<input>` on each iteration that a `<li>` was created and append the `<input>` to the `<li>`

Comment: @itsjustGavin updated with checkboxes.

Comment: thank you, I’m new to this and this has helped me greatly. I’ll run the code in my editor when I get home from work.